# Value error while one hot encoding a variable in the jupyter notebook for a neural network

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook

In the code below I am attempting to create a neural network that tries to replicate classical music. I am trying to one hot encode the output variable with this line of code:

```
y = np_utils.to_categorical(dataY)
```

but it gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-0b5dca9da053> in <module>()
     65 X = X / float(n_vocab)
     66 # one hot encode the output variable
---> 67 y = np_utils.to_categorical(dataY)
     68 # define the LSTM model
     69 model = Sequential()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py in to_categorical(y, 
num_classes)
     26     y = y.ravel()
     27     if not num_classes:
---> 28         num_classes = np.max(y) + 1
     29     n = y.shape[0]
     30     categorical = np.zeros((n, num_classes))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in amax(a, axis, 
out, keepdims)
   2318 
   2319     return _methods._amax(a, axis=axis,
-> 2320                           out=out, **kwargs)
   2321 
   2322 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _amax(a, axis, out, 
keepdims)
     24 # small reductions
     25 def _amax(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
---> 26     return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
     27 
     28 def _amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False):

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no 
identity
```

Below is the complete code:

```
import glob
import pickle
import numpy
from music21 import converter, instrument, note, chord
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

def get_notes():
   """ Get all the notes and chords from the midi files in the ./midi_songs 
   directory """
   notes = []

   for file in glob.glob("smaller classical music repertoir/*.mid"):
     midi = converter.parse(file)

     notes_to_parse = None

     parts = instrument.partitionByInstrument(midi)

     if parts: # file has instrument parts
         notes_to_parse = parts.parts[0].recurse()
     else: # file has notes in a flat structure
         notes_to_parse = midi.flat.notes

     for element in notes_to_parse:
         if isinstance(element, note.Note):
             notes.append(str(element.pitch))
         elif isinstance(element, chord.Chord):
             notes.append('.'.join(str(n) for n in element.normalOrder))

  with open('C:/Users/emili/Documents/python projects/music data/notes1', 'wb') as filepath:
    pickle.dump(notes, filepath)

 return notes


notes = get_notes() 

# create mapping of unique chars to integers
chars = sorted(list(set(notes)))
char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

# summarize the loaded data
n_chars = len(notes)
n_vocab = len(chars)
print ("Total Characters: ", n_chars)
print ("Total Vocab: ", n_vocab)

# prepare the dataset of input to output pairs encoded as integers
seq_length = 100
dataX = []
dataY = []
for i in range(0, n_chars - seq_length, 1):
    seq_in = notes[i:i + seq_length]
    seq_out = notes[i + seq_length]
    dataX.append([char_to_int[char] for char in seq_in])
    dataY.append(char_to_int[seq_out])
n_patterns = len(dataX)
print ("Total Patterns: ", n_patterns)

# reshape X to be [samples, time steps, features]
X = numpy.reshape(dataX, (n_patterns, seq_length, 1))

# normalize
X = X / float(n_vocab)

# one hot encode the output variable
y = np_utils.to_categorical(dataY)

# define the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), 
return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(46))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

# define the checkpoint
filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}-bigger.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, 
save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

# fit the model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=1000, batch_size=64, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

edit: For some reason, the code works when I compile it in sublime text but not in the jupyter notebook.

Comment: Check if your y data has any nan

Comment: @ShashiTunga If print my Y data it gives me  ' [] '. But I think the problems lies somewhere with the use of the jupyter notebook because when I compile the code in sublime text it works fine.